# mysql adding constraints to compound primary key

Tags: mysql, magento, constraints, innodb, referential-integrity

this is actually a magento 1.4 table named `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx` with a primary key on 3 fields, but my question is meant to be generic to mysql practices:

- entity_id
- customer_group_id
- website_id

All of the tables in this version are innoDB, and most all of the tables have constraints (USUALLY ON DELETE CASCADE) back to the proper primary key elsewhere.

However, this table is different; there are no constraints, and `entity_id` is definitely leading back to `catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id`

Simple question, how would you add a constraint to a fractional part of a primary key? Are there any problems with this or things I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sure possible http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3eea9/2

Only thing is that the foreign key needs the column to be *first* in some index, as shown with the `t3.b` - but MySQL creates such index automatically for you